# How to make a white char in ruby string?

Tags: ruby, whitespace

I use this query to database:

```
Category.all.each { |c| c.ancestry = c.ancestry.to_s + (c.ancestry != nil ? "/" : '') + c.id.to_s 

   }.sort {|x,y| x.ancestry <=> y.ancestry 
   }.map{ |c| [" A " * (c.depth - 1) + c.name,c.id]}
```

Before the letter **A** I want to add a few white chars (because of indentation), but if I tried to add just `" "` (empty space) or `\t`, it doesn't work.

How to do that?

Comment: Not related to your question, instead of the `sort` method, you can use `sort_by { |x| x.ancestry }` (or `sort_by(&:ancestry)` as a shortcut), which has better performance. With `sort`, the `ancestry` method gets called twice on each step, whereas with `sort_by` it gets called only once for every item in the array.

Comment: You should really do the positioning in CSS instead of relying on the width of a whitespace. Maybe you could use a nested unordered list (`<ul>…</ul>`) as a starting point and you would get a proper html structure that maps the structure of your content as far as i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is on a webpage. If so, more than 1 space in HTML is ignored. Instead, you need to use CSS to space each category, or use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces.

Comment: Yes, it does on a webpage. I have already tried to use `&nbsp;`, but this chars is printed as `&nbsp;`, not convert to empty space. The code above is used into `<select>` tag.

Comment: In that case, `&nbsp;` is the right thing. Read up on string escaping  . `.html_safe`, and `h` are your friends.